# Unable to boot after depleting the battery

Tags: boot, dell, battery

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Dell XPS 13 ultrabook. I left the laptop on for a couple of days so the battery ran out. After that I am getting a black screen when I try to boot up the laptop. This happens even before I can see the Dell logo.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't even see the Dell logo or access the bios, then the hardware is busted.  You'll have to take it back to Dell.